# Protecting my RSA Private Key Password when decrypting data

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

I generated a public and private key to use for encryption purposes. There is a passphrase connected to the private key but I know I shouldn't be showing it in plain text like this.

What should I do to protect this password so it isn't shown in plain-text?

```
// $data = encrypted data using RSA public key
// $key = the key that came along with the encrypted data

// find private key
$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey("file:///path/to/private.pem", "PASSWORD");

// try and decrypt the data using private key
openssl_open($data, $decrypted_data, $key, $pkeyid);

// if all went well, show decrypted data
echo $decrypted_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this to what extent do you need to go to protect your password(s)?

Why not save it in a secure file and read it in when needed?

Below is a list of levels you can go through to ensure maximum protection of master keys. Each step will add more protection to the previous step.

1. Isolation of the masterkey in a repository on a secure server
2. Restriction of access to server containing the masterkey
3. Encryption of the masterkey in the repository. (See [Red Key/Black Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RED/BLACK_concept))
4. Randomness and frequent changing of the masterkey

Comment: Thanks for the comment Irb. By master key do are you referring to the password to get the private key?

Comment: Yes, referring to the password.